# Why does declaring pointer makes it contents nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, pointers, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declared but unset variable evaluates as true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518686/declared-but-unset-variable-evaluates-as-true)

Why does this code work on Mac OS

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str;
    NSLog(@"%@", [str length]);

    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and console output is

```
2011-09-23 15:37:17.481 Untitled1[80021:903] (null) 
2011-09-23 15:37:17.495 Untitled1[80021:903] Hello, World!
```

but crashes on iPhone ?

Comment: What is the message in the log?

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes.
First, you declare pointer str, don't set it's value and use it in NSLog.
Second, you use formatting %@, but supply integer value ([str length]), result is undefined. That's why on simulator it prints null, but crashes on device.

Answer (score 3):

You were just lucky.  Local variables are uninitialised and could contain anything.  It's likely that on OS X, str contains 0 (aka nil), sending `-length` to nil returns 0.  Then you are treating the length (which is an `NSInteger`) as a pointer for the `NSLog`.

If the length is 0, the `NSLog` will treat it as a nil pointer if the format specifier is `%@` and will print `(null)`.

If `str` has a random non zero value, either your program will crash when you send length or if it miraculously works and returns a non zero length, it'll probably crash trying to treat it as an  object pointer in NSLog

Answer (score 1):

the value is never initialized (or set). it could be any random value. in debug, it may be zero-iniitalized.

a crash (or some UB) is what you should expect in this case. so... turn up your compiler and static analyzer warnings, fix the issues, and always initialize your values.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
     NSString *str=@"";

NSLog(@"%d", [str length]);
```

Answer (score -2):

See ,
You can call only release method over a nil object. other than release method we cannot call any method over a nil.

Here you are calling a method ( length )over an object which is pointing to nil , in this case it should point to nsstring object in general before sending length message .