# Aren't objective-c pointers nil until when you allocate the memory?

Tags: objective-c

I thought that when I declare an object the pointer is still nil until when I allocate memory and initialize it. Instead I run this code and I was surprised to see that it outputs "TRUE":

```
NSString * aString; 
        if (aString) {
            NSLog(@"TRUE");
        }
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declared but unset variable evaluates as true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518686/declared-but-unset-variable-evaluates-as-true)

Comment: Instance variables and static variables, yes. Local variables, no, unless using ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pointing at an undefined location - it can point to any memory location (even one that you don't have access to.

You should `NIL` it out when declaring it.

Comment: +1. To the OP - you need to explicitly set them to nil if you need them to be.

Comment: @Daniel A. White So, if you don't immediately declare an object do you set it to nil in the declaration line ?

Comment: @Patrick, Yes, if you need an automatic to be at some defined state then set it to nil to start. That code should produce a compiler warning explaining that fact.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate an OBJECT the storage is nilled, but when you have an automatic variable it's whatever junk it is.